# How to add field below previously added field via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to add an `input` when a `button` in the `form` is clicked. However, the field adds above the previously added field rather than below it.

I am using jQuery's `insertAfter()` to add the field after a particular element (which happens to be the default field that is already existing).

```js
$("#add_email").click(function() {
  $('<input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter email address" type="email" name="emails[]" class="woocommerce-Input input-text">').insertAfter("#first_inemail_field");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first_inemail_field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter email address" type="email" name="emails[]" class="woocommerce-Input input-text">

<button type="button" class="woocommerce-Button button btn btn-success" id="add_email">Add another email</button>
```

I want the newly created field to appear below the field created before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you always insert after the `#first_inemail_field`, hence the new fields always go second in the group of inputs.

To fix this you could instead use `insertBefore(this)` to put the new field just in front of the button which was clicked:

```js
$("#add_email").click(function() {
  $('<input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter email address" type="email" name="emails[]" class="woocommerce-Input input-text">').insertBefore(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first_inemail_field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter email address" type="email" name="emails[]" class="woocommerce-Input input-text">
<button type="button" class="woocommerce-Button button btn btn-success" id="add_email">Add another email</button>
```

To extend this further, you could use `clone()` to remove the HTML from your JS code, which should be kept as separate as possible. Note that I removed the `id` attribute from the `input` in this example as it's no longer needed and saves creating duplicates.

```js
$("#add_email").click(function() {
  $('input[name="emails[]"]:first').clone().val('').insertBefore(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter email address" type="email" name="emails[]" class="woocommerce-Input input-text">
<button type="button" class="woocommerce-Button button btn btn-success" id="add_email">Add another email</button>
```